# How can I add data to the end of the file without breaking the file scheme

Tags: python, file

For example I want to add 1 line string data to end of the pdf / ppt / png / jpg / xlsx etc. file.But I know every file format has a scheme.
String should not appear in the page content but must be found at the end of the file.
How can I do this ?

In my job I implemented a hash function and I have to add the string to the end of the file.But for example when I add a char to xlsx file.Excel shows an warning that file is corrupt.

Comment: Each format needs to be dealt with separately, there is no general way. xlsx is an archive, you can unpack it and pack it back.

Answer (score 0):

For .xlsx file you can use the module called "pandas" and more specifically the function `pandas.read_excel(PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE)` you can find out more about it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#excel-files

Comment: not just xlsx ,  doc , docx , pdf , ppt ,xls etc files